# Appending script in iFrame dynamically in window.load function

Tags: jquery

I have a html page as `a.html` where I have some `content` , an `iframe` and a `button`.

**a.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        // some content
        <button id="insert">Insert</button>
        <iframe id="outputContentLoadContainer" src=""  height="290px" width="100%" style="border:none"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

On click of `button`, I am filling `src` attribute of `iframe` with another `html` say `b.html` file, which is loading properly.

**b.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            #container{
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOW:**

When user clicks on Insert I am inserting another button to iframe body and event handler for the button like this

**JS:**

```
$("#insert").on('click',function(e) {   
    $("#outputContentLoadContainer").attr("src","b.html");          
    appendHtml = '<button id="test"> Test</button>';
    appendjs = '$(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#test").click(function(e){
            alert("hi");
        });       
    });';   
}); 

$("#outputContentLoadContainer").attr("src","b.html").on('load', function(){
    $(this).contents().find("body").find('div#container').append(appendHtml);
    $(this).contents().find("style").append(cssArray);
    $(this).contents().find("script").append(appendjs);
});
```

**The problem is**

I have the output where my `test button` appears and even `js` appears in the script tag `b.html` but the event does not work? why? I am suspecting that script should loaded on `window.load`. Kindly help.

Comment: iFrame is an independent of outside window. I would suggest to load this script on `$(document).ready()` of *b.html*.

Comment: @Rajesh I am aware of this and doing so, the problem is it's not working.....

Comment: You are inserting script on click of a button, so it will add it to same page. iFrame will work independently. You cannot pass anything to iFrame from outside.

Comment: If you want to perform some action based on a flag, you can send it as query parameter.